# Format the results of a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to retrieve Azure service bus queues who has exceeded a specific message count, and the script is working well so far, but when it retrieves the values, it just does it in the following format:

> The limit has been exceeded for the following queues:q1-monitoring-endpoint q1-monitoring-endpoint q2-monitoring-endpoint q3-monitoring-endpoint

I need to retrieve them in a better format.
Here is the script, I'm using:

```
$NS = Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace
    foreach ($NS in $NS)
    {
        $Queue = Get-AzureRmServiceBusQueue -ResourceGroupName $NS.ResourceGroup -Namespace $NS.Name
        if ($Queue.MessageCount -eq 0 )
        {
            "The limit has been exceeded for the following queues:" + $Queue.Name
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to an Azure subscription at the moment to test this, but consider doing something along these lines:

```
Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-AzureRmServiceBusQueue -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroup -Namespace $_.Name |
            ForEach-Object {
                [PsCustomObject]@{
                    Queue = $_.Name
                    LimitExceeded = ($_.MessageCount -eq 0)
                }
        }
    }
```

This will (hopefully) produce output similar to the following:

```
Queue  LimitExceeded
------ -------------
Queue1 False
Queue2 True
Queue3 False
```

Not only is this a neater format than the original string output, it means you get some objects as output, which can be further manipulated.

Answer (score 2):

You should explain "in a better format". However, your main issue is within your foreach loop where you try to iterate over `$NS` but assign the current object to `$NS`. You need to choose a different variable:

```
$NS = Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace
    foreach ($N in $NS)
    {
        $Queue = Get-AzureRmServiceBusQueue -ResourceGroupName $N.ResourceGroup -Namespace $N.Name
        if ($Queue.MessageCount -eq 0 )
        {
            "The limit has been exceeded for the following queues:" + $Queue.Name
        }
    }
```

---

**Note**: I would recommend to retrieve all empty queues and save it in a variable (which enables you to use it later):

```
    $emptyQueue = Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace | 
        ForEach-Object {
           Get-AzureRmServiceBusQueue -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroup -Namespace $_.Name 
        } |
        Where-Object MessageCount -eq 0
```

Finally, output it in your desired format:

```
Write-Host "The limit has been exceeded for the following queues: $($Queue.Name -join ',')"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the edit you have done to my script generate the results in the same format. The other one displays the following error: Get-AzureRmServiceBusQueue : The input object cannot be bound because it did not contain the information required to bind all mandatory parameters:  Namespace
At line:2 char:5

Comment: Well, I don't know which output you expect so I didn't changed the format, I just fixed your issue. Regarding the error you get, I corrected my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Format commands available in powershell to get the output in a better format.

You can define your custom format as well with Format-Custom command.

Reference for Format commands in Powershell : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/using-format-commands-to-change-output-view?view=powershell-6